# Confused about WdPasteOptions enumeration in Word VBA

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am using Word 2013.

The WdPasteOptions enumeration contains the following:

```
wdKeepSourceFormatting 0 Keeps formatting from the source document.
wdMatchDestinationFormatting 1 Matches formatting to the destination document.
wdKeepTextOnly 2 Keeps text only, without formatting.
wdUseDestinationStyles 3 Matches formatting to the destination document using styles for formatting.
```

These are used for the four paste options:

```
PasteFormatWithinDocument
PasteFormatBetweenDocuments
PasteFormatBetweenStyledDocuments
PasteFormatFromExternalSource
```

The dialog in Word includes an choice of "Merge Formatting" for all four options, but there is nothing in the enumeration whose name matches this. Upon inspection, the "Merge Formatting" choice has a value of 1, corresponding to wdMatchDestinationFormatting.

The simplest explanation would be that what Word now calls "Merge Formatting" used to be "Match Destination Formatting." A less plausible explanation is that Word changed the options so that "Merge Formatting" not only has a different name but behaves differently from "Match Destination Formatting."

Does anyone know whether these two refer to the same functionality or different functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No one not from Microsoft can say for certain, but...

As far as I know, "Merge Formatting" would be the same as matching destination formatting. This is Word's original, design default in order to make it easier to seemlessly combine documents from different sources into one  "coherent" document.

FWIW I have my doubts whether those four object model enumerations exactly match the UI commands. I think you also need to throw the Paste Special options into the mix to get closer to the full spectrum.

The object model commands are written before the Word UI is finalized for the version in which things are introduced - so commands in the UI may well not match the name of the corresponding part of the object model.

In addition, Microsoft may decide to change the caption of a command in the UI at a later point. For reasons of backwards compatibility the name of the corresponding part of the object model will **not** be changed. This means tha code which worked in earlier versions will continue to run in newer versions.

Comment: It's really great to be reminded of some of the reasons that any software app has certain evolutionary or historical oddities.